# falla el ApplicationDbContext con base de datos mysql

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Por qué me da error en el **ApplicationDbContext** conectado a base de datos **mysql** ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCInBuiltFeatures.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data;   


ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

  public ActionResult Index()
        {

           var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            return View(roles);

        }
```

me da ese error

> Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct

en el web config este es el codigo

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MyMVCTraining;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=demo;Password=demo; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: no estoy seguro pero dime si te ayuda esto. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154283/entity-framework-database-connection-error

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el atributo providername de la cadena de conexión y tambien debes agregar MySql a los providers de Entity Framework como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```